# How can i check mobile data or wifi is on or off. ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, internet-connection

in my app i am checking that if mobile data is off its showing the popup like check your data connection. for that i write this code

```
 import Foundation
import SystemConfiguration

public class Reachability {

    class func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool {

        var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in(sin_len: 0, sin_family: 0, sin_port: 0, sin_addr: in_addr(s_addr: 0), sin_zero: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
        zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(zeroAddress))
        zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

        let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(&zeroAddress) {
            SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(kCFAllocatorDefault, UnsafePointer($0))
        }

        var flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags(rawValue: 0)
        if SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability!, &flags) == false {
            return false
        }

        let isReachable = flags == .Reachable
        let needsConnection = flags == .ConnectionRequired

        return isReachable && !needsConnection

    }
}
```

but by this code its only check that wifi is connected or not. but if i try with 3g mobile data its always showing me that your mobile data is not connected. so how can i solve this?

Comment: This works for me: [link](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift)

Comment: This is working. while i connected via wifi. but its not working while i connected via mobile data @DadoZolic

Answer (score 4):

Try like below code:

Create object of reachability class like,

```
    var internetReachability = Reachability()
```

Now write below code in viewDidLoad(),

```
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "reachabilityChanged:", name: kReachabilityChangedNotification, object: nil)
    self.internetReachability = Reachability.reachabilityForInternetConnection()
    self.internetReachability.startNotifier()
    self.updateInterfaceWithReachability(self.internetReachability)
```

Now create function to check reachabilty of wifi as well as data pack,

```
func updateInterfaceWithReachability(reachability: Reachability)
{
    let netStatus : NetworkStatus = reachability.currentReachabilityStatus()
    switch (netStatus.rawValue)
    {
    case NotReachable.rawValue:
        print("offline")
        break
    case ReachableViaWWAN.rawValue:
        print("online")
        break
    case ReachableViaWiFi.rawValue:
        print("online")
        break
    default :
        print("offline")
        break
    }
}

// Rechability update status
func reachabilityChanged(sender : NSNotification!)
{
    let curReach : Reachability = sender.object as! Reachability
    self.updateInterfaceWithReachability(curReach)
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: should i use same Reachability() class?

Comment: Yes. Do you have that library?

Comment: No i am using it by making public class

Comment: Ok but you can also download that library online like from this : https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability

Answer (score 3):

**Don't require 'Reachability' pod**

**Swift 4+ and Xcode 11+**

```
    import SystemConfiguration    

    protocol Utilities {}
    extension NSObject: Utilities {
        enum ReachabilityStatus {
            case notReachable
            case reachableViaWWAN
            case reachableViaWiFi
        }

    var currentReachabilityStatus: ReachabilityStatus {

        var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
        zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout<sockaddr_in>.size)
        zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)
        guard let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(to: &zeroAddress, {
            $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {
                SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, $0)
            }
        }) else {
            return .notReachable
        }

        var flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = []
        if !SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability, &flags) {
            return .notReachable
        }

        if flags.contains(.reachable) == false {
            // The target host is not reachable.
            return .notReachable
        }
        else if flags.contains(.isWWAN) == true {
            // WWAN connections are OK if the calling application is using the CFNetwork APIs.
            return .reachableViaWWAN
        }
        else if flags.contains(.connectionRequired) == false {
            // If the target host is reachable and no connection is required then we'll assume that you're on Wi-Fi...
            return .reachableViaWiFi
        }
        else if (flags.contains(.connectionOnDemand) == true || flags.contains(.connectionOnTraffic) == true) && flags.contains(.interventionRequired) == false {
            // The connection is on-demand (or on-traffic) if the calling application is using the CFSocketStream or higher APIs and no [user] intervention is needed
            return .reachableViaWiFi
        }
        else {
            return .notReachable
        }
    }
}
```

In any method use the below condition

```
if currentReachabilityStatus == .notReachable {
    // Network Unavailable
 } else {
    // Network Available
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have any super Class in your application then use below code

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
    {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)


        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "ShowNetConnectivity", name: SHOW_NO_INTERNET_CONNECTION, object: nil)

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "DisssmissConnectivity", name: DISMISS_INTERNET_CONNECTION, object: nil)


        let reachability = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(nil, host)!
        SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback(reachability, { (_, flags, _) in
            print(flags.rawValue)

            if (flags.rawValue == NotReachable.rawValue && flags.rawValue != ReachableViaWiFi.rawValue && flags.rawValue != ReachableViaWWAN.rawValue)
            {
                if(isConnectionAvailable == true)
                {
                    let nc = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
                    nc.postNotificationName(SHOW_NO_INTERNET_CONNECTION, object: nil)
                }
            }else
            {
                if(isConnectionAvailable == false)
                {
                    let nc = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
                    nc.postNotificationName(DISMISS_INTERNET_CONNECTION, object: nil)
                }
            }

            }, &context)

        SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop(reachability, CFRunLoopGetMain(), kCFRunLoopCommonModes)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool)
    {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: SHOW_NO_INTERNET_CONNECTION, object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: DISMISS_INTERNET_CONNECTION, object: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I do it and it works for me.
In my viewDidLoad:

```
do {
        reachability = try Reachability.reachabilityForInternetConnection()
    } catch {
        print("Unable to create Reachability")
        return
    }

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
                                                     selector: #selector(MainViewController.reachabilityChanged(_:)),
                                                     name: ReachabilityChangedNotification,
                                                     object: reachability)

    do {
        try reachability.startNotifier()
    } catch {
        print("This is not working.")
        return
    }
```

And the **reachabilityChanged**

```
func reachabilityChanged(note: NSNotification) {

    let reachability = note.object as! Reachability

    if reachability.isReachable() {
        if reachability.isReachableViaWiFi() {
            print("Reachable via WiFi")
        } else {
            print("Reachable via Cellular")
        }
    } else {
        showNoConnectionAlert()
        print("Not reachable")
    }
}
```

Using this [Reachability](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift)

Answer (score 1):

I use [this pod repo](https://github.com/Shmoopi/iOS-System-Services) to achieve not only wifi or mobile data. you can do much more with it and you can use it in ObjC or Swift.

Best regards.

Comment: Why using pods and bind your code to an external dependency if you can achieve the goal with built-in tools?)

Comment: @rommex why re-write the wheel if someone else has already coded it for you?

Comment: @RonLugge Why be dependent on somebody’s code (and its interface, its hidden bugs, its constrained logic) if it is easily dine natively?